# When using rails class.build it continues the flow of id's instead of starting from zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having a problem by trying to automatically generate a number of 50 seats per every session, in my event management app...

Since when i build seats they always continue their unique identifier, which of course makes sense, but in this case since i have it nested under the Sessions, i would prefer to have something more concise like session/1/seat/1 to 50

Should I somehow pass params to it?

```
def create
@Session = Sessions.new(session_params)

for i in 0..50
  @session.seats.build
end

@session.save
respond_with(@session)
end
```

Comment: That identifier needs to be separated from the primary key then. And a number would have to be specified in parameters. A lot to do here.

Comment: Can you give us the code for the models? It's pretty difficult to guess what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by doing a little of refactoring in the database and adding another integer.

```
for i in 0..50
  @session.seats.new(:seat_number => i)
end
```

Comment: Note that `0..50` is a total of **51**.

Comment: Glad you solved it on your own too! Consider accepting one of the answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

The object's id refers to its class, not to some other entity that the object might be related with.  So, as *D-side* said, for the functionality you are describing you will need to have another field in your `seats` model.

For example, you can call this `seat.number` and do something like

`50.times do @session.seat.new(:number => @session.seats.count + 1)`

That way, all the seats for a session will be numbered from 1 to 50.